# How to create Yii2 Breadcrumbs

Tags: yii2

I am looking for yii2 beadcrumb code

I have layout page in twig want to add breadcrumb there and want to update it according to pages for example

Dashboard/Employees/Add Employee

Dashboard/Employee/Edit Employee

Dashboard and employee will be clickable

I got very less information on yii2 breadcrumbs on internet.

Comment: "Hello I need code..." isn't a particularly useful way to open a question.  We are professionals, not code vending machines.

Comment: thanks Claies i got your point but it was humble request not order

Comment: I found your question usefull,  and it's on top of google results looking for "yii 2 how to use breadcrumbs"

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In your main layout use:

```
<?= 
   Breadcrumbs::widget([
      'homeLink' => [ 
                      'label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Dashboard'),
                      'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
                 ],
      'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
   ]) 
?>
```

And in your view:

```
$this->title = 'Add Employee';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Employees', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
```

This will generate the following breadcrumbs:

```
Dashboard / Employees / Add Employee
```

Comment: great! thats what totally i need sir, nice one! big thanks!

Comment: @ValRob: I guess you can check the controller & action name and then decide whether you want to show it or not. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

In your layout-

```
//use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;

<?= 
   Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
   ]) 
?>
```

In your view-

```
$this->title = 'Example';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: Hi **SuperBiasedMan** I wrote it, it works also like this

Answer (score 1):

**My Code looks like this:**

```
<section class="content-header">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <?php
        echo Breadcrumbs::widget([
          'itemTemplate' => "<li><i>{link}</i></li>\n", 
          'homeLink' => [ 
            'label' => Yii::t('yii', 'Dashboard'),
            'url' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
          ],
           'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
       ]);
        ?>
     </ol>
    </section>
```

and on any of the view page it I add a snippet

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = "Item Details";
```

The above is a simple example. The issue with this is that it does not truly give out the tree structure for navigation. I will have to write a helper function to track the history or tree path for each view page.