# Create breadcrumbs using category structure in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have implemented a view to show category structure using Yii2.

Users can navigate sub categories by clicking root category. Child categories are shown in the same page when page has been refreshed.

I need to show breadcrumbs according to category navigation. I set category titles according explanations. But it shows current category without showing the category hierarchy.

I have gone through few previously asked questions. But there were not a solution for my question.

[How to create Yii2 Breadcrumbs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940465/how-to-create-yii2-breadcrumbs)

[Yii2: How can I place something into a Breadcrumbs widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29747698/yii2-how-can-i-place-something-into-a-breadcrumbs-widget)

Is there anyone who has same kind of experience and found a solution?

Thanks.

=============================Edit==================================

```
    $this->title = 'Curriculum Lists';
    $request = Yii::$app->request;
    //Get data
    $get_data = $request->get();

    //This is for page 
    if($get_data['cat'] === 'yes'){
        $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
    }else{
        $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label'=>$this->title, 'url'=>['category-list/categories', 'parentid' => "1", 'cat'=>'yes']];
    }

//Get categories
$categories = (isset($dataProvider['categories'])) ? $dataProvider['categories'] : "";

//Get parent data
$parent = (isset($dataProvider['parent'])) ? $dataProvider['parent'] : "";

//Create breadcrumb for current category
if($get_data['cat'] === 'no'){
    $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $parent['category_list_value'], 'url' => ['category-list/categories', 'parentid'=>$parent['category_list_id'], 'cat'=>'no']];
}

//Show categories
if(!empty($categories)){
    foreach ($categories as $cat) {
        $pid = $cat['category_list_id'];
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<a href="index.php?r=category-list/categories&parentid='.$pid.'&cat=no">';
        echo $cat['category_list_value']."- ".$pid;
        echo '</a>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: is better If you show your code

Comment: @scaisEdge I have added code for your reference.

Comment: Finally I was able to implement breadcrumbs using stack data structure. PHP implementation of stack is SplStack. See more here - http://php.net/manual/en/class.splstack.php